# Shim-client java chaincode Hyperledger Fabric 1.1

Tags: java, maven, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am writing chaincode in Java using Fabric shim-client. I read in tutorials that we need to generate the jar by checking out Fabric source code.

I did that for development and wrote chaincode. But, It's impractical to generate jar manually by everyone who wants to work with the project.

It's been about a year now since Fabric team released their tutorials. **Does anyone has actually uploaded shim-client jar to Maven**? If so, what are the dependencies? Are we **still suppose to manually generate the jar**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After wasting about a day, finally, I found the jar pointing to the latest java shim client. I am sharing this as a reference, maybe it would help someone else.

I am using gradle, I used following setting in my build.gradle file.

```
repositories {
maven {
    url 'https://nexus.hyperledger.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
}
mavenLocal()
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compile group: 'org.hyperledger.fabric', name:'fabric-chaincode-shim', version: '1.2.0-SNAPSHOT'

}
```

This will get you the latest java shim client.

[image: Check the latest jar]

Hope this helps.